# Do some helicopters require classes, type ratings, or special endorsements, the way some airplanes do?

Tags: helicopter, pilot-certification

I've been looking online for the different ratings and classes of helicopters but I can't find much.

For example in fixed wing aircraft you have retractable gear, constant speed propeller, IFR, multi-engine, tricycle gear, etc.

I am curious to know what the helicopter equivalents are. What does a basic helicopter rating allow you to fly? What comes after that?

Comment: I attempted to make the title of your question more clear, but if I misunderstood your intent, please feel free to revert it.

Comment: @SteveV. no problem, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Are you asking in the context of FAA regulations?

Comment: @JonathanWalters an FAA regulation would be great if you have one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a connection between "classes" of helicopters and ratings.

You also don't specify which jurisdiction so I will answer for the UK CAA which I know.

To fly any helicopter under VFR needs nothing more than your license, gained on any type, and a type rating for the specific aircraft.

For example, I gained my license on the R22.  I am therefore also type rated on it.  The second aircraft I learned to fly was the B206 which is jet powered.  I didn't need anything extra than the appropriate type rating.

I can fly any helicopter for which I am rated under VFR.  If I had an IFR certification, I could fly any helicopter I am rated for under VFR, and any IFR certified helicopter for which I am rated under IFR.

"Difference training" is simply part of the the type rating.  For example, if I ever learned to fly a craft with a retractable undercarriage, I would be rated to fly that type, but not another type with retractable gear.

What does differ is the type of license, e.g. CPL or ATP.  I would need that license in order to carry passengers for hire and to conduct other commercial operations, but I still need a type rating on whatever helicopter I use to carry those passengers.

Put it this way, the day after I gained my license, I could climb into any helicopter and act as pilot under training.

Hope that's all clear!

Answer (score 4):

***Note:*** This answer is given for [faa-regulations](/questions/tagged/faa-regulations)

---

### Short Answer:

`Rotorcraft` is an aircraft *category*; `helicopter` and `gyrocopter` are *classes* of the `rotorcraft` *category*.

### Longer Answer:

[14 CFR 1.1](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.1) defines aircraft Categories and Classes for airman certification, and gives examples of each. In these definitions `helicopter` is included under *classes*; `rotorcraft` is included under *categories*.

[14 CFR 1.1, Category](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.1):

> Category:
>
> (1) As used with respect to the certification, ratings, privileges, and limitations of airmen, means a broad classification of aircraft. Examples include: airplane; **rotorcraft**; glider; and lighter-than-air;

[14 CFR 1.1, Class](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.1):

> Class:
>
> (1) As used with respect to the certification, ratings, privileges, and limitations of airmen, means a classification of aircraft within a category having similar operating characteristics. Examples include: single engine; multiengine; land; water; gyroplane; helicopter; airship; and free balloon;

Elsewhere in chapter 14 of the CFR, helicopter is given as a class of the rotorcraft category, for example in [§61.161](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=240fddea648bce985de5daa723e48195&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1161&rgn=div8)

> §61.161   Aeronautical experience: Rotorcraft category and helicopter
>   class rating.
>
> (a) A person who is applying for an airline transport
>   pilot certificate with a rotorcraft category and helicopter class
>   rating, must have at least 1,200 hours of total time as a pilot that
>   includes at least:

Therefore, we see that `helicopter` is a class and will not have any sub–classes. `Helicopter` and `gyrocopter` are the *classes* of the `rotorcraft` *category*.